# What date format does Oracle/Toad expect?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, toad

In the Toad editor, I've got this SQL:

```
SELECT INTERLOPERABCID,AVAILABLEDATE,
AVAILABLEQHR,CARPHONEID,
TRUNC((AVAILABLEQHR-1)/12) "COL",
MOD(AVAILABLEQHR-1,12) "ROW"
FROM ABC.INTERLOPERAVAILABILITY
WHERE INTERLOPERABCID>42
AND AVAILABLEDATE='09/Apr/2012'
```

...but it returns no rows, even though I see many records in the table whose AVAILABLEDATE value = '4/9/2012'

The date format ('09/Apr/2012'; I also tried '04/Sep/2012') looks odd, but at least I get no compilation/execution error with it. When I tried "4/9/2012" and "04/09/2012" it said "ORA-01853: not a valid month"

How must I enter the date to tell it I want to see dates of April 9th, 2012?

Comment: The date format depend on the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, that depends on NLS_TERRITORY. Both can be session specific. Never rely in a 'default' dateformat, use a proper date mask in to_date functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safest to use TO_DATE:

```
AND AVAILABLEDATE = TO_DATE('09/Apr/2012', 'DD/Mon/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ):

```
SELECT INTERLOPERABCID,AVAILABLEDATE,
AVAILABLEQHR,CARPHONEID,
TRUNC((AVAILABLEQHR-1)/12) "COL",
MOD(AVAILABLEQHR-1,12) "ROW"
FROM ABC.INTERLOPERAVAILABILITY
WHERE INTERLOPERABCID>42
AND AVAILABLEDATE = DATE '2012-04-09'
```

Are you sure there is no time part in your dates?

Comment: The Data type is "Date" and there is no time element that displays in the DB for that column.

Comment: Both of the answers work, so which one to choose as "the" answer was a tossup.

Comment: This is quite unusual that you have to prefix the date with the DATE type specifier. I would have never expected it as I assumed oracle would be clever enough to cast it or whatever like the sql server does.